# Validation Of Success Message in Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hello Guys I am trying print out "The product has been added to your shopping cart" from the popup window which disappears in 10 seconds,  In the console After I add product,Could someone assist me with that
String expectedTitle = "The product has been added to your shopping cart";

```
    if(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle)){

        System.out.println("Title bar message verified successfully");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Title bar message verification failed");
    }
```

the above is what I used not so sure , if that's the right way.
[image]

String expectedTitle = "The product has been added to your shopping cart";

```
    if(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle)){

        System.out.println("Title bar message verified successfully");

    }else{
        System.out.println("Title bar message verification failed");
    }
```

tried the above code , and the result I see in console "Title bar message verification failed"

Comment: How are you extracting the `actualTitle` ? Add the full `code` ?

Comment: I fixed the issue the selector was wrong , thank you for your response

Comment: How are you geting the _`actualTitle`_?

Comment: Yes I could Extract the actual title and here's the code to it                                                                                        String actualTitle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#bar-notification p.content")).getText();

        System.out.println(actualTitle);
        String expectedTitle = "The product has been added to your shopping cart";
        if(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Title bar message verified successfully");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Title bar message verification failed");
        }